# Unit testing entry file in React

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, entry-point

I am writing unit tests for an entry (aka root or index) file in React.

No documentation seems to have been written about unit tests for entry files in React.

Is unit testing entry files in React necessary? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to the App.js entry file in React. Yes you can write tests for it. Almost test anything in react. Assume the App.js file below

```
export default class App extends Component{

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Navbar />
          <Routes />
          <Footer />
        </div>          
     </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

You could test for what you expect the file to contain or do.

- Test that App.js should have Navbar, Footer and Routes components.
- Use snapshot test App.js

Test - App.test.js

```
describe('<App />', () => {
  it('should render without breaking', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<App />);
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
  it('should contain the routes component', ()=>{
    const wrapper = shallow(<App />);
    expect(wrapper.containsMatchingElement(<Routes/>)).toEqual(true);
  });
});
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I still don't know if it's possible to write tests for an entry file in React.

However, I learned that the right thing to do is to put the strict minimum in the entry file so that there is little point in testing it. All testable code will be in children files.